# I can modify a React Native component attribute that is a string, not but not a (non-state) object: Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In trying to explore the behavior of props, state, and other attributes of React Native components, I came across the following behavior, which I don't understand.

Suppose we create a class `App` so that is has a string-valued attribute called `myCity` that is immediately changed after it is defined:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  myCity = 'SF';
  myCity = 'Oz';

  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style = {{fontSize: 44, textAlign: 'center'}}>
          {this.myCity}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In this case, the immediate modification of `myCity` triggers no error and the app renders 'Oz' as expected.

If we replace the two lines defining `myCity` by the single line

```
myState = {city: 'Oz'};
```

and modify the corresponding value passed to the Text component to be

```
this.myState.city
```

then the app again renders 'Oz' as expected.

However, if we try to immediately modify the value of `myState.city`, then an error is triggered and the app is no longer rendered:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  myState = {city: 'SF'};
  myState.city = 'Oz';

  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style = {{fontSize: 44, textAlign: 'center'}}>
          {this.myState.city}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```
SyntaxError: App.js: Unexpected token
  myState = {city: 'SF'};
  myState.city = 'Oz';
  ^
```

Why is that?

Comment: Add the error to your question.

Comment: Believe your question has to do with the fact that javascript objects are passed by reference, as opposed to scalar values.

Comment: You're trying to write code in a random location--in the original example you're creating a property, which allows initialization. In the second you create a property then have regular code where it isn't allowed.

Comment: @DaveNewton:  Why isn't it allowed?  Are there references you could point to?

Comment: @ethane: I edited to add the error.

Comment: @DavidRomano Because that's how the language was designed? The language spec.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Are you saying this is part of ES6 and not React Native?

Comment: @DavidRomano React Native is written in JavaScript (except for the native parts, obviously).

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, but which spec are you saying is generating the error -- ES6 or the React Native library?  I don't think it's ES6, but I can't find any reference for React Native that would point to this as not being allowed.

Comment: @DavidRomano React Native is a library--it doesn't define language semantics.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, but it could be the React Native library that's triggering the error, and that it's not an issue with the Javascript.  It sounds like you're convinced it's Javascript issue -- is that correct?

Comment: @DavidRomano The error is pretty specific: a syntax error. React Native’s user code is JS(X), so that’s where the syntax error is. Libraries don’t create their own syntax (roughly speaking).

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for persisting; it's been helpful for guiding searches to find an answer, which is still elusive. It seems the error was thrown by intermediate parser for React before it gets transpiled to Javascript.  (It seems ES6 does not allow assignments to occur within a class, so even the first, error-free code example I gave would throw a syntax error.)

Comment: @DavidRomano It's a proposal (don't know the status) but supported by Babel--that *is* the transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
myCity = 'SF';
myCity = 'Oz';
```

in this case, you are just defining a class variable `myCity` and assigning 'Oz' to the class variable `myCity`, which overrides the previous statement not modifying any property of it.

```
myState = {city: 'SF'};
myState.city = 'Oz';
```

But here you are trying to modify a property of `myState` which is a no no.
you can do

```
myState = {city: 'SF'};
myState = {city: 'Oz'};
```

to make it work, or if you want to do it like `myState.city = 'Oz';`, Do that in a constractor.

Comment: I guess part of my question is why it's a no-no -- why does modifying an object value trigger an error?